# BSOD on Hyper-V after creating Virtual Network on Intel NIC

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2008-r2, nic, bsod

I have a home server with a Gigabyte P55M-UD2 motherboard, 16GB of DDR3 RAM, a i5 760 proc and 2 off-board Intel(R) Pro/100+ Management Adapter NICs. I installed a Windows 2008R2 Enterprise on my machine, and I've enabled Hyper-V role. Whenever I create a new Virtual Network on one of the 2 Intel NICs, I start getting BSOD all the time. On the onboard Realtek RTL8168D/8111D NIC, everything goes well.
On the System Event Viewer, I always get a Information from Iphlpsvc Source:

```
Isatap interface isatap.{59553F6E-9CA2-456E-B940-CB57991053EA} with address fe80::5efe:192.168.1.5 has been brought up.
```

After, I get an Error, from BugCheck Source:

```
The computer has rebooted from a bugcheck.  The bugcheck was: 0x000000d1 (0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000002, 0x0000000000000000, 0xfffff88002f3c3f1). A dump was saved in: C:\Windows\MEMORY.DMP. Report Id: 101310-23930-01.
```

If I remove the Virtual Network for the NIC, I stop getting BSOD. Is there anything I can do to avoid this, and use these 2 NICs, or will I have to get new ones that are compatible with Hyper-V?
Tks

Comment: This is the danger you face when you use machines that aren't on the hardware compatibility list.

Comment: I had to change the NICs... no other way.. but thanks for everyone's help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you updated your intel nics to their latest drivers?  In my experience, BSOD is at a hardware and driver level.

Comment: According to this link (http://www.intel.com/support/network/sb/CS-030613.htm), I'm suppose to use "In Box" Drivers...